# Date format changed when printing RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

In my `WinForm` application I have several RDLC reports. In some of the reports, I have `textBox` that shows `Execution Date`. When the report loads, the date format is exactly what I need i.e. `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt`. But when try to print or print preview, it changes to `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`. Why so?

I have set the `TextBox` to `=Global!ExecutionTime`.

Below are the images for the same...
First is loaded report and second is Print Preview.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2d2e6d4-3f7d-4c5f-8810-4801e5ef88a0/reportviewer-date-format